# Discord.js | Displaying a username from an ID returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, leaderboard

I'm currently changing my server's leaderboard command to display on a Canvas, rather than an embed. A problem I ran into is that since it's not an embed, grabbing the user's IDs then displaying their usernames with `<@userid>` no longer works, the code just returns the ids as plain text. I'm looking for a solution to fix this. Here is the code I have right now:

```js
for (var i in money) {
    let user = client.users.cache.get(`${money[i].ID.slice(25)}`);

    finalLb += `${money.indexOf(money[i])+1} ${user} \`${money[i].data} credits\`\n`;
    console.log(user)
  }
```

Result of code

[image]

When I console log the user variable, I get all their info, including the username.

[image]

I tried user.username, but get the error `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`. I am a bit stuck at this point, any help's appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.username` does work if `user` is defined. By checking your first image, you can see that the ninth user is `undefined` there too. As the user is `undefined`, you can't get the `username` property.

Are you sure the ID you get from `${money[i].ID.slice(25)}` is correct? If it is, maybe try to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) the users instead:

```js
for (var i in money) {
  let user = await client.users.fetch(`${money[i].ID.slice(25)}`).catch(console.error);

  finalLb += `${money.indexOf(money[i]) + 1} ${user.username} \`${
    money[i].data
  } credits\`\n`;
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the user ID's are correct, when displaying it from an embed, all usernames show up correctly, in the @username format, Looks like that code still displays the same thing, "<@userid>"

Edit: After switching up the user declaration to include await, I also added username to ${user.username}, looks like that worked!

Comment: I've just added `username` too :)

Comment: Will do! I appreciate the help :) Also, No worries if you can't help out with this, but I was also wondering how I could display the avatarURL of each user on the leaderboard? Next to their name.